# UIWebView references in blank ionic project

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am going through a nightmare regarding the UIWebView depreciation by Apple. I am in the process of identifying the cordova plugins and hopefully will find solutions. However, when I start from a blank ionic project, I still see references with respect to UIWebView and puzzled by it. Below please find the steps I followed:

1) ionic start testProject blank --cordova
2) Add the below into the ios section of the config.xml:

```
<preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>
<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
```

3) ionic cordova prepare ios
4) cd platforms/ios
5) grep -Ri UIWebView

At this point, I see references at CDVUIWebViewEngine.m

If I were to install the following:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
npm install @ionic-native/in-app-browser
```

I also see references related to inappbrowser

I am not sure what is going on with such a basic structure. I'd grateful for any pointer you may have as I have been pulling my hairs for the last two days.

Below is my setup:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.7.0 (/home/doug/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.1.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.901.7
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 9.1.7
   @angular/cli                  : 9.1.7
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : ios 5.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 6 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res                          : 0.14.0
   native-run (update available: 1.0.0) : 0.2.9
```

Thanks,

Doug

Comment: To be clear: was your app rejected by Apple or are you just anticipating it?

Comment: Hi Sebastien, thanks for your reply. I have not submitted the empty project. I was trying to figure out why my proper app was rejected and was hoping to keep adding plugins but noticed the references at the empty project. Should I ignore such references?

Comment: I'm not sure if you definitely can ignore them. But given that you are using all the latest version of all those frameworks, I would be surprised thaht they had not addressed that well-known issue. Also, did you use the `usewkwebview` for the cordova-plugin-inappbrowser plugin?

Comment: Just in case, have you tried Capacitor as a bridge instead of Cordova? I know it uses only WKWebView out of the box. It also has a [Browser API](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/browser) to open webviews, although not as configurable as some Cordova options.

Comment: Many thanks Sebastien. I indeed tried the usewkwebview but apparently I am doing something wrong I guess. I noticed that cordova-ios@6.0.0 just got released and it dropped UIWebView. I hope the plugins will also transition to that. Thanks again